# Foldr issues (Haskell)

Tags: haskell, fold

I'm trying to convert from a table which is of type `([Char, Int])` to a string `tab2str :: Table -> String` (that follows some specific formatting patterns.)

I'm using foldr (as the title implies) but I'm having some issues getting the exact function to work - i.e. It errors. My function looks like this:

`tab2str xs = foldr (++) ' ' $ map (\char count -> show char ++ ':' ++ show count ++ '\n') xs`

The output should be each letter in the table, a colon, then `\n`. So a test might be:

`tab2str test1 == "F: 1\no: 1\nl: 1\nd: 1\nr: 1\n"`

where 
`test1 == [(F, 1), (o, 1), (l, 1), (d, 1), (r, 1)]`

Any help gratefully received.

Comment: Functional programming tip: code that uses `foldr` like this is often difficult to read.  `foldr` is best used to write "intermediate" utility functions that you then use to solve your concrete problems.  For example, `map`, `filter`, `(++)`, `concat` and many other standard list functions are all `foldr` under the hood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After minimal corrections this typechecks:

```
tab2str xs = foldr (++) " " $ map (\(char, count) -> show char ++ ":" ++ show count ++ "\n") xs
```

– but produces not quite what you want.

You'll probably like this better:

```
tab2str table = concat $ map formatRow table
    where formatRow (char, count) = [char] ++ ": " ++ show count ++ "\n"
```

Then your test example:

```
ghci> let test1 = [('F', 1), ('o', 1), ('l', 1), ('d', 1), ('r', 1)]
ghci> tab2str test1
"F: 1\no: 1\nl: 1\nd: 1\nr: 1\n"
ghci> putStr $ tab2str test1
F: 1
o: 1
l: 1
d: 1
r: 1
ghci>
```

Comment: you can improve this by using concatMap and removing table paramter

Comment: @Arjan I don't think that'll improve readability. But indeed, that will make the code a bit shorter.